# Matching array of string to numbers to get database values

Tags: php

In my database, I have a status column where I'm using numbers to represent a status of a product. Each of these numbers represents a string value, for example 1 is open, 2 is closed, etc. Now to display a count of these statuses in my webpage, I am converting the following numbers into a string to display them to the user:

```
array(1=>'Open',8=>'Hot',2=>'Closed',3=>'Transacted',4=>'Dead',9=>'Follow Up',11=>'Working')
```

Now I have this count as a clickable link, where the user can click the count and it takes them to a new page showing the details of that item. For which I'm using this:

```
<a target='_blank' href='".site_url('reports/viewall?status=' . $status)."'>".$num."</a>
```

This correctly passes the argument to the URL and shows `http://localhost/reports/viewall?status=Closed`

Now I'm storing this variable in my controller as $status, but I cannot use this string value in  my model query which is this since it is giving the string value of status and not the number related to it:

```
SELECT * from TABLE1 where status = $status
```

Controller Class where I'm storing the $status:

```
$status = $this->input->get('status');
$content['individualleads'] = $this->leads_model->get_all_leads($status )->result();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best approach would be to pass the integer in the URL and use the array text value only when it is text meant for the user.  So just:

```
http://localhost/reports/viewall?status=2
```

Another alternative is to flip the array and access the text key:

```
$status_num = array_flip($array)[$status];
```

Or search the original array:

```
$status_num = array_search($status, $array);
```

Probably more standard might be to have a `status_types` table with the integer `status_id` and text `status_text` for each status and join this when retrieving the status.